# Play Framework Error: play.sbt.PlayExceptions

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm new with play framework. I have a project but it is causing me problems.

I use Play Framework 2.5.9 along with ebean 3.0.2. The error is as follows:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[value where is not a member of com.avaje.ebean.Finder[Long,models.Viaje]]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

Also the errors that are generated are related to the model classes. In each of these classes I have defined the following method:

```
public static Finder<Long, Motorista> find = new Finder<Long,Motorista>(Motorista.class);
```

And I make any query following the following nomenclature:

```
Motorista.find.findList ();
```

or:

```
Motorista.find.where (). eq ( "id", 1);
```

The issue is that the above error is always followed by errors in all the lines where I make those queries the error says:

```
value findList is not a member of com.avaje.ebean.Finder [Long, models.Motorista]
```

and

```
value where is not a member of com.avaje.ebean.Finder [Long, models.Motorista]
```

I think that maybe it is a configuration problem, although the project was working well for me.

My build.sbt file contains the following

name := """siiaf"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

And my plugins.sbt file contains the following:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.9")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean).
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.2")
```

Pleease need help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that he was making inquiries in the Scala views, for example:

```
ModelClass.find.where().eq ("id", 1).findList()
```

And according to the documentation of play framework 2.5.x that is not possible:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaEbean

> Play has been designed to generate getter/setter automatically, to
>   ensure compatibility with libraries that expect them to be available
>   at runtime (ORM, Databinder, JSON Binder, etc). If Play detects any
>   user-written getter/setter in the Model, it will not generate
>   getter/setter in order to avoid any conflict.
>
> Caveats:
>
> (1) Because Ebean class enhancement occurs after compilation, do not
>   expect Ebean-generated getter/setters to be available at compilation
>   time. If you’d prefer to code with them directly, either add the
>   getter/setters explicitly yourself, or ensure that your model classes
>   are compiled before the remainder of your project, eg. by putting them
>   in a separate subproject.
>
> (2) Enhancement of direct Ebean field access (enabling lazy loading)
>   is only applied to Java classes, not to Scala. Thus, direct field
>   access from Scala source files (including standard Play templates)
>   does not invoke lazy loading, often resulting in empty (unpopulated)
>   entity fields. To ensure the fields get populated, either (a) manually
>   create getter/setters and call them instead, or (b) ensure the entity
>   is fully populated before accessing the fields.

The solution was then to include in the template the following:

```
@import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean
```

And make in the template, a query like this:

```
Ebean.find(classOf[ModelClass]).where().eq("id",1).findList()
```